# how do i change the date of birth in Cisco

Tags: cisco-ios

error:"Due to GDPR requirements, you must be at least 16 years old to participate in Networking Academy."
This error popped up as I mistakenly chose the wrong date of birth, how can I change the Date of Birth in Cisco

I tried changing the date of birth in the settings but there were only options like, change in password and email but I couldn't find the option to change the Date of Birth